# Trouble with NSDictionary functions in Swift

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, swift

I have the following `imageMap` that returns `NSDictionary` within a `Class` called `WXCondition`:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)imageMap {
    // 1
    static NSDictionary *_imageMap = nil;
    if (! _imageMap) {
        // 2
        _imageMap = @{
          @"01d" : @"weather-clear",
          @"02d" : @"weather-few",
          @"03d" : @"weather-few",
          @"04d" : @"weather-broken",
          @"09d" : @"weather-shower",
          @"10d" : @"weather-rain",
          @"11d" : @"weather-tstorm",
          @"13d" : @"weather-snow",
          @"50d" : @"weather-mist",
          @"01n" : @"weather-moon",
          @"02n" : @"weather-few-night",
          @"03n" : @"weather-few-night",
          @"04n" : @"weather-broken",
          @"09n" : @"weather-shower",
          @"10n" : @"weather-rain-night",
          @"11n" : @"weather-tstorm",
          @"13n" : @"weather-snow",
          @"50n" : @"weather-mist",
      };
    }
    return _imageMap;
}
```

I then have the following method that returns the `imageMap` method:

```
- (NSString *)imageName {
    return [WXCondition imageMap][self.icon];
}
```

I am trying to convert these methods to Swift and so far I have the following:

```
func JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> NSDictionary {
    return {
        "date": "dt",
        "locationName": "name",
        "humidity": "main.humidity",
        "temperature": "main.temp",
        "tempHigh": "main.temp_max",
        "tempLow": "main.temp_min",
        "sunrise": "sys.sunrise",
        "sunset": "sys.sunset",
        "conditionDescription": "weather.description",
        "condition": "weather.main",
        "icon": "weather.icon",
        "windBearing": "wind.deg",
        "windSpeed": "wind.speed"
    }
}

func imageName() -> NSString {
    return "" //[WXCondition imageMap][self.icon];
}
```

Not quite sure how to return an `NSDictionary` properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `+` method is called a `class` method. In Swift you use the keyword `class`. If you need an `NSDictionary` you can create a normal dictionary and then just use the `as` keyword (you can also bridge it to objective c, but this is more explicit). So this is what you will end up with:

```
class func blah() -> NSDictionary {
    return [
        "date": "dt",
        "locationName": "name"
        // ...
    ] as NSDictionary
}
```

Your second function (although I don't see much information on it) could probably just be modified to something like: `return WXCondition.imageMap()[self.icon]` (you may need to include `as NSString` depending on where the information is coming from and what you are attempting to do with it)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class A {
    class func myDict() -> NSDictionary {
        var occupations = [
            "Malcolm": "Captain",
            "Kaylee": "Mechanic",
        ]         
        return NSDictionary(dictionary: occupations)
    }
}
println("Test = \(A.myDict())")
```